# How do I conditionally display a field in Infopath?

Tags: conditional-statements, infopath

I'm trying to do the following in infopath: I have to choose between 2 options (with bullets), and depending on this, if we choose Option1, I need to display a text field to enter more details, but if Option2 is chosen, I don't need this additional field.

I'm not sure about how to enter a Rule to define this :-(
Anyone could help?
Thx!

Answer (score 3):

In 2010, you do this with 'Rules' (changed from 2007). Open the Home tab in the ribbon, open Manage Rules from there. Then select your control, and add / edit rules in the rules pane for each control to achieve what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

In InfoPath 2007, you can:

- Right click on any control
- Select Conditional Formatting
- Enter a condition that maps to option 2 being chosen
- Click "Hide this control" as the formatting to apply.

You probably want to put this and any descriptive field text inside a section; and hide / show it using the steps above.

Answer (score 0):

In InfoPath 2013, you can:
You can hide Controls on the basics of a condition using Formating Rules.

1. Click on the control
2. Add Rule
 
3. Select Formatting
 
4. Add Condition
5. Check Hide Control